# removing vowels from string javascript, why is my solution not working?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a remove the vowels from the string prompt. For some reason my code is not working, I keep getting an undefined. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance! Looking for simple and readable code. Is there a way to do this with recursion?

```
const removeVowels = function(string){
  let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
  let vowelIndex = [];
  for(let i=0; i<string.length; i++){
    if(vowels.includes(string[i])){
      vowelIndex.push(i);
    }
  }
  for(let i=0; i<vowelIndex.length; i++){
    string.slice(vowelIndex[i])
  }
}
console.log(removeVowels('happy')); //want 'hppy'
```

Comment: `slice` does not operate on itself; your string.slice statement does nothing

Comment: if you operate with ```slice``` on the string then it will return the result in the new string the existing string value will remain the same.

Comment: Right, by “does nothing” I meant “is useless without an assignment”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason my code is not working

Here are the primary reasons. First you are not returning from the function so console.log is `undefined`. Secondly in function you are using `slice`. It gives back the extracted part of string. So for example after extraction of first letter sat `h` from `happy` it will be `appy` and also at same time the index of the characters in the word will change. In `happy` , `a` was at index `1` but if you use slice to extract a character in new string `appy` `a` will have index `0`.

Alternatively you can use an array to include words from string which are not in vowel list. Then return the array by joining all the characters

```js
const removeVowels = function(string) {
  let vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  let words = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (!vowels.includes(string[i])) {
      words.push(string[i]);
    }
  }
  return words.join('');
}
console.log(removeVowels('happy'));
```

Another approch is to use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and replace all vowels with `''`

```js
const removeVowels = function(string) {
  return string.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '')
}
console.log(removeVowels('happy'));
```

Comment: That makes sense, I have to practice with the .slice method too

Answer (score 2):

Strings in js are iterable so you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get an array of characters

You can simply use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the `vowels` and then join the characters using [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) you can create a string again.

```js
const removeVowels = function (string) {
  let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  return [...string].filter((c) => !vowels.includes(c)).join("");
};
console.log(removeVowels("happy")); //want 'hppy'
```

Comment: Oh I never thought to use the spread syntax, I like that idea!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const removeVowels = function(string){
  const vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
  return string.split('').filter(char => !vowels.includes(char)).join('')
  
}

console.log(removeVowels('happy')); //want 'hppy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is needlessly complicated. All you have to do is loop through each character and check whether the array contains the character.

Try:

```js
const removeVowels = function(string) {
  let vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  var str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    str += vowels.includes(string.charAt(i)) ? '' : string.charAt(i);
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(removeVowels('happy')); //want 'hppy'
```